# Recursive method to get the number of occurences of an element in a binary tree

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

[image: photo of my non-recursive code]

Hi. I am having trouble writing this method (in the photo) in a recursuve format. The method gets the amount of occurences of a given element in the binary search tree.
To solve this recursively, I was trying to implement it with a private helper method of the same name, like this:

```
public int count(){
count = 0;
if (root == null)
    return count;
return count (root.getInfo());

private int count(T element){
(Basically the same code you see in the photo)
}
```

but I ended up with overflow errors. Would you mind taking a look and telling me how I can structure this method recursively?

Cheers, and thanks.

Comment: root is not a local variable of the function, this can be a reason for the error. You want a recursive function but you are using a loop which doesn't make sense and "root = root.getLeft()" inside the if condition doesn't make sense too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tentative implementation may looks like this.

```
public int count(T element, T root){
   if(element == null) {
      return 0;
   }
   int count = 0;
   int compare = element.compareTo(root.getInfo());
   if(compare == 0){
      count++;
   }
   count += count(element, root.getLeft());
   count += count(element, root.getRight());
   return count;
}

count(item, root);
```